# Entity Framework Core API return table with .Include

Tags: rest, api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Model with ICollection:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

This works with MVC:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Blog.Include(l => l.Posts).ToListAsync());
}
```

I try to use **API-Controller**:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
....
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Blog> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Blog.Include(l => l.Posts).ToList();
}
```

This generate a error:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 44 of the JSON data**

How to return a multidimensional Json with Blogs and for every Blog entry all Posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

This is a error in JSON serialization.

Add in Startup.cs to Mvc ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
 ....
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
   return Ok(_context.Blog.Include(l => l.Posts).ToList());
}
```

If you try async wrap IActionResult in Task

Comment: No, same problem "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 44 of the JSON data"
Return String is:
[{"id":1,"name":"TestBlog","posts":[{"id":1